# Responsive Menu Expand Upward or Remove

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, nav

It has been a while since I have needed to rely on this awesome community of experts and I am hoping that someone can save me from sanity here.

I have a site that everything works great on except the responsive menu is doing funny things only on ipad in portrait view (768px). Normally I can figure out and modify the media queries for various things but I cannot for the life of me figure this one out.

Problem: at 768px wide the mobile menu is at the bottom of a container that will not expand to display all contents. I have seen other menus move upwards before in the opposite direction, but cannot figure out how to do it and don't know if that would be possible here.

I have no issues with the mobile nav at any other size. That being said, I would be happy removing the mobile nav at 768 since the main menu will actually fit, but for some odd reason I couldn't get it to do what I wanted (first time for everything I guess).

I am hoping that I am missing something really silly here and that it is an easy fix. Unfortunately it is a wordpress theme that is no longer supported by the author (go figure).

P.S. this is only an issue on the home page as the nav placement is at the top of all other pages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Site url: http://markreeder.ca/photography

Thank you in advance. Have a great night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `bottom:100%;` something like here:

```
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    font: 10px;
    bottom: 100%; /* added this attribute */
}
```

Comment: You may just be a genuis! Give me one second. I tried it in firebug and it worked. Let me just add it to query before marking as approved answer!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Took a little bit of tweaking in css just because of the white on black, but you got me in the right direction and provided me a good night sleep!

Comment: Heh yw mate :) I just finished my gf's WP blog responsive sticky bar today and had plenty of hours to play around with css :P